# Angular templates in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I have Rails 3.2.8 application. The part of the app is using angular and I'm running into some issues with angular templates. My idea was to have structure like this:

```
app/
  angular/
    templates/
      hostings/
        email_accounts.html
        show.html
        index.html
```

Now, in development mode everything works as expected but in production mode after running `rake assets:precompile` strange thing happens: The angular html templates are placed, as expected, under the public folder, but only email_accounts.html and show.html. **The index.html is lost.**

Comment: nope, huge application, where parts are written in rails, parts inn angular.

Comment: Just because it's a huge app doesn't mean it's not a single page app :) I only ask because index usually needs to be a bootstrap for partials in your config with `ng-view` consuming index in a rake with other partials could cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that Sprockets gives special meaning to "index" files stored in a subdirectory, treating them as manifest files for the files within the subdirectory.  This may be your issue.